# Meta-analysis - no control groups!

Tags: r, meta-analysis, academia, systematic-review

I am conducting a meta-analysis of volumetric growth rates of a specific tumour type, per year, after surgery. The studied included have no control groups, but rather arms of interventions. I am looking to meta-analyse pre-op and post-op tumour size and see what affects tumour growth more. To account for follow-up period as a confounding factor I will calculate the post-op tumour size per 1 year, and standardise it just like that. How would I be able to meta-analyse my findings? What are the types of effect size would I be looking at?

Since I am looking at tumour size my data is definitely not dichotomous.

Cannot be odds ratio as no control groups.

The most common thing I saw is meta-analysis of proportions. I have no clue what that means, or how to do it since I don't know anything about R.

PS. "meta-analysis" here = Do you have several independent studies of the same tumour type whose results I am trying to combine into effect sizes i.e. forrest plot diagram.

Comment: Please say more about what you mean by "meta-analysis" here. Do you have several independent studies of the same tumor type whose results you are trying to combine? Or are you analyzing tumors in a new study? Please provide that information by editing the question, as comments are easily overlooked and can get deleted.

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what the individual studies you have contain as it seems they may compare two or more treatments. If that is the case I would strongly recommend getting a biostatistician as a collaborator as network meta-analysis is not going to be easy if you cannot use statistical software. There should be no need to standardise if you include length of follow-up as a moderator.